# Submit a form to current URL in magento admin custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I am creating a custom module in which a specific `admin role` can load funds to customer coupon card based on the scanned copy of bills submitted by the customer.

So I created a separate interface as below

[image]

So once respective admin user click on load funds for should be submitted to current page and I have the customer id in the URL and I can get the id and load funds to customer account.

My current URL will be

> http://192.1.0.8/store_coupon/index.php/finansier/adminhtml_store/view/id/1/key/8c44f33d2fe7019ccce1462e1376c498/

I created a template file like below

```
 <div id="page:main-container">
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div class="content-header">
    <table cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:50%;"><h3 class="icon-head head-sales-order">Order Item</h3></td>
          <td class="form-buttons">
           <form method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getCurrentURL()?>" id="edit_form" name="edit_form">
              <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
              <button title="Create New Order" type="submit" class="scalable add" style=""><span><span><span>Load Funds</span></span></span></button>
            </form>
            <button title="Create New Order" type="button" class="scalable button" style=""><span><span><span>Complete Delivery</span></span></span></button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="box-left">
    <!--Order Information-->
    <div class="entry-edit">
      <div class="entry-edit-head"> <a href="">Order # 100000001</a> </div>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <table cellspacing="0" class="form-list">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="label"><label>Order Date</label></td>
              <td class="value"><strong>Apr 10, 2016 5:42:15 PM</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="label"><label>Placed from IP</label></td>
              <td class="value"><strong>192.168.100.68</strong></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-right">
    <!--Account Information-->
    <div class="entry-edit">
      <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4 class="icon-head head-account">Account Information</h4>
        <div class="tools"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="hor-scroll">
          <table cellspacing="0" class="form-list">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="label"><label>Customer Name</label></td>
                <td class="value"><strong>XXXXXXX</strong> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="label"><label>Email</label></td>
                <td class="value"><a href="mailto:anto@anto.com"><strong>xxx@xxxx.com</strong></a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
      <h4 class="icon-head head-products">Item Ordered</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid np">
    <div class="hor-scroll">
      <table cellspacing="0" class="data order-tables">
        <colgroup>
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr class="headings">
            <th>Product</th>
            <th><span class="nobr">Qty</span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr">Bills Submitted For</span></th>
            <th>Customer Info</th>
            <th>Delivery Mode</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="even">
          <tr class="border">
            <td><div class="item-container" id="order_item_5">
                <div class="item-text">
                  <h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_5_title">Condensed MILK</span></h5>
                  <div><strong>SKU:</strong> S - MGC - 002</div>
                </div>
              </div></td>
            <td class="a-left">1</td>
            <td class="a-left">$ 50</td>
            <td class="a-left"> Address Goes Here
            </td>
            <td class="a-left">Collect</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this is not working, Can some one suggest me on this?

**EDIT** May be I am not explaining clearly. When my current page URL is http://192.1.0.8/store_coupon/index.php/finansier/adminhtml_store/view/id/1/key/8c44f33d2fe7019ccce1462e1376c498/

page should be submitted here itself,

Comment: can you describe what is not working you want to show the template or anything else?

Comment: I mean form is not submitting to current URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`

```
<button style="" class="scalable button" type="submit" title="Create New Order" ><span><span><span>Complete Delivery</span></span></span></button>
```

for current url

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1, can you check edit section on my question.

Comment: you want submit page on load?

Comment: NO, when cashier role user clicks on load fund page should be submitted to current page itself

Comment: you already added the submit there this will work when use will click on that it will submit.

Comment: Yes I understood, I changed the `submit` from `button` based on your answer thats right, Now I would like to submit the form to current page itself. I mean if my current page renders from UserController/view action form should be submitted to same page itself

Comment: `$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();` try that for current url